# Deleting only one link which should be removed from list

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
<a href="/portfolio/${portfolio.id}" data-portfolio-id="${portfolio.id}" data-bookmark-id="${bookmark.id}" class="ac-hns">
    <span>${portfolio.title}</span>
    <span>By ${portfolio.ownerName}</span>
    <img src="${portfolio.coverImage()}" alt="">
</a>
<a href="/portfolio/${portfolio.id}" data-portfolio-id="${portfolio.id}" data-bookmark-id="${bookmark.id}" class="ac-hns">
    <span>${portfolio.title}</span>
    <span>By ${portfolio.ownerName}</span>
    <img src="${portfolio.coverImage()}" alt="">
</a>
```

JS

```
$('.ac-hns').on('click', '.icn-close-white', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteBookmarkItem( $(this), $(this).parent().attr('data-portfolio-id'), $(this).parent().attr('data-bookmark-id') );
});


function deleteBookmarkItem( btn, itemID, bookmarkID ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/bookmarks/'+ bookmarkID,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function( response ) {
            $('.ac-hns').remove();
            console.log('delete portfolio from bookmark');
        }
    });
}
```

The items are dynamic via json. If delete one of items on the list, say 3 items under one same bookmark, one item should be removed under the same bookmark and it wouldn't be on same bookmark anymore.

But right now, click on close icon on one of the items, all the items are removed under the same bookmark which is not right.

Help or insight appreciated.

Update
Just realize - could remove data-bookmark-id="${bookmark.id}" from  tag and it won't appear in the bookmark list. I tried removeData('data-bookmark-id'), but it doesn't take bookmark id out.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$('.ac-hns').remove();` removes all element with class .ac-hns.

You have to specify on your script which element with class of .ac-hns should be removed.

And since you want to change the whole group, it's parent including other child elements, do this `$(itemID).remove();`

Edit: also `$(this).parent().attr('data-portfolio-id')` when you pass as parameter, remove the .attr so it will only pass the parent and thus when you `$(itemID).remove();`, the script will able to know which parent it is then remove that element including its children.

Comment: thanks - i followed will's example - $('[data-portfolio-id="'+itemID+'"]').remove(); item disappears but after one item, it shows errors hmm

Answer (score 0):

`$('.ac-hns').remove();` in the callback is removing everything with that class. Hard to tell with your HTML structure but I think you want something like this:

```
function deleteBookmarkItem( btn, itemID, bookmarkID ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/bookmarks/'+ bookmarkID,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function( response ) {
            $('[data-bookmark-id="'+bookmarkID+'"]').remove();
            console.log('delete portfolio from bookmark');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: yeah that's what i am looking for. but it seems that it removes almost everything? I am not sure till I test with more than 1 items in same bookmark group. Perhaps, ajax is not necessary to do delete ?

Comment: Without seeing your complete html, I couldn't say why it's deleting almost everything. For instance, `cly-ac-hns` doesn't exist in your example html! Presuming that each `<a>` element has a unique *data-bookmark-id* attribute, `$('[data-bookmark-id="'+bookmarkID+'"]').remove();` should only remove that one.

Comment: yeah you are right, and i have corrected the name. it works if I use itemID instead and it will be unlinked to bookmark.

Comment: one more thing, after deleting all items, the bookmark list should stay even if there is no portfolio items. Was type: 'delete' a issue?

Comment: Again, need more HTML to answer that.